# Getting issue with my page menu when drawing it in my Phone or small devices

Tags: css, menu

When putting any box or content on body my drawable menu going down when opening the page in my phone or small device. Using HTML and CSS.

Code can be checked at
[www.deworb.com/home.html](http://www.deworb.com/home.html)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because,  this question doesn’t meet StackOverflow guideline.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the SO. The question does not meet the guidelines. It simply lacks specific information to be able to understand your problem correctly. Please include your code in non-url format, as when your website does not longer exist in the future, then nobody benefits from this question. Also please describe exactly, what is the issue, its vague at best right now. And why not include a screenshot? Your question will be voted open (in case it gets closed), once you edit it with correct input. And your problem is clearly in the lack of z-index in the header {}

Comment: Agreed... Now this can be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `z-index` to the `nav` tag plz check the attached image.

`z-index:99;`

[Please have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2hLy.png)

Answer (score 1):

you should add z-index to the sidebar element with value higher than value of z-index in other elements (default value of z-index is 0).

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  header {
    padding: 0 20px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,
Now issue is resolved.
I have just added z-index: 1; under Header Nav